# How to remove item from QQueue at index i

Tags: qt

How to remove item from QQueue at index i.

Answer (score 5):

Being that QQueue is based on and will work like a std::queue, which is a FIFO (First-in First-out container), it seems you may need to rethink your usage of QQueue.

To remove the head item, use

```
QQueue::dequeue()
```

To remove an item at index i (using QList inherited functions)

```
QQueue::removeAt( int i )
```

If you need to do this, rethink your QQueue usage please.

(see Qt Documentation)

Comment: It will not remove the last item. It will the remove the item at the head of the queue. From Qt documentation, dequeue() is equivalent to  QList::takeFirst().. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qqueue.html#dequeue .. It sums it up..

Answer (score 1):

`QQueue` inherits `QList<T>`, so you can use `void QList::removeAt(index)` inherited method.

Answer (score -1):

Qt documentation for,

```
T QQueue::dequeue ()
```

states that, **Removes the head item in the queue and returns it. This function assumes that the queue isn't empty.**

Hope it helps.

Edit:

If you want to remove item from a specific index, use `QList` instead.

There are functions like,

```
void QList::removeAt ( int i )
```

and

```
T QList::takeAt ( int i )
```

which you can make use depending upon your need..